# CarrierWave Gem won't update properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, carrierwave

I'm attempting to use Carrierwave in rails 5 and am not having much luck using array file uploads on updates.

I have a form with several fields and a file select button.  I can create and save the initial object without any trouble.  The problem comes in when I try to do an update with something like @my_object.update_attributes(my_object_params).

If I try to add additional files when updating the form my initial files are overwritten with the new files.  Even if I do something like this beforehand:

`original_images = @my_object.find(params[:id]).images
new_images = params[:my_object][:images]
@my_object.images = original_images + new_images`

Doing a "puts" here shows the newly added files, as well as the original files are in @my_object.

Calling @my_object.save only allows the files to be saved and won't update the form fields.  So using this isn't really a viable option.
If I call @my_object.update_attributes(my_object_params), or @my_object.update(my_object_params). The form fields are updated, but the files in the array are completely rewritten with only the newly updated files.  This seems bizarre to me since I updated the file array in @my_object with both the original and new files.

Apparently there aren't any callback methods to prevent this behavior as stated in the README file.  I just get an error when trying to use a callback stating the callback method has not been defined.

ie:
`
- after_commit :remove_previously_stored_my_object, on: :update . (Singular Version obviously won't exist)
skip_callback :commit, :after, :remove_previously_stored_my_object

- after_commit :remove_previously_stored_my_objects, on: :update (I would expect a plural version to be available)
  skip_callback :commit, :after, :remove_previously_stored_my_objects
  `

I've been working on this issue for a week and unfortunately I cannot find a solution.  I will have to pull out carrierwave and do everything manually if I cannot resolve this soon.  This would obviously not be ideal.

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AkIwXX8N29F3RWpd9OpmnPDpUTiCEKP3Z02+a8/zWBeZxuKR3gt uNjfwtJIhIyWCet7zBxAOq9WWjBr291SItw==", "my_object"=>{"name"=>"test 123", "discription"=>"test 123", "my_object_dt(1i)"=>"2018", "my_object_dt(2i)"=>"3", "my_object_dt(3i)"=>"8", "images"=> –
 `[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ffc2b1eb340 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/lx/zh78w2d93bq 1s_s5v4z_6r0h0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180308-30502-1c1f20r.pdf>, @original_filename="add_file3.pdf", @co ntent_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"my_object[images][]\"; filename=\"add_file3.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">, etc. etc. etc.`

I simply followed the CarrierWave README example and have taken exactly what is shown for multiple avatars.  Unfortunately doing an update overwrites the files and the callback methods don't exist.  Unfortunately they don't provide an example on how to do an update.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

[Multiple Avatars ActiveRecord Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrpSW.png)

Please help!  Thanks.

Comment: do your "new_images" have `id` values? can you post a minimal (even pseudo) example of what your `params` look like?

Comment: Are your images stored inline with the object? As in this is not a has many relationship? If so I would recommend changing your schema to `class MyObject; has_many :images; end` and `class Image; belongs_to :my_object; end` but I cannot help based on what you have posted. Also please edit your post rather than adding important details in the comments section

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking. When I upload files they are ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile objects, which do not have id's.

I have an array of files stored in a JSON column within my object (MyObject).

Comment: `
my_object = MyObject.last

my_object.images
`
This will return an array of files produced by the carrierwave gem column (JSON).

Comment: My point is don't store these in a column store them in a table as a one to many with whatever my object is

Comment: Got it!  :) . I'll try that.

Comment: Oh, I don't think that will work because the requirement is that each file shares the same meta-data fields associated with its siblings, which must be searchable.

Comment: So according to the CarrierWave site adding the following to your uploader should resolve the issue, but it doesn't work.

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  configure do |config|
    config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = false
  end

  ...
end

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Keep-uploaded-files-(for-a-specific-uploader)

Comment: You are not removing them you are overwriting them completely. I do not understand this part "meta-data fields associated with its siblings, which must be searchable." Storing the images in a 1 (my_object) to many (images) relationship makes the most sense but since you have chosen such ambiguous terms it is difficult to help. Maybe try and share the actual real world problem in as simple terms as possible.

Comment: I need one object with multiple images.  For example, Album.  Album will have fields associated with it (ie: name, description, etc...).  This is not possible if you have a has_many association because you would need one Album object per image.  I need one album object per multiple images.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I just put my foot in my mouth.  LOL .  Album has_many images and image would then have a single attached file.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes it is a very simple relationship http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association